# Loadin new images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i load a new image in place of another using jQuery?

I hope to do this possibly by clicking a button for previous or next. See below for an example. **Important: i dont know how many pictures on server (1 or 100). So, i cant load them all on web page load. and cant do array in javascript code on same reason**

```
showing /img/1.jpg (click on button 'next')
showing /img/2.jpg (click on button 'next')
showing /img/3.jpg (click on button 'prev')
showing /img/2.jpg (click on button 'prev')
showing /img/1.jpg (click on button 'prev')
```

Comment: is there a reason you want to do this all yourself?
i agree with you if you need a very lightweight solution, but there are quite some jquery plugins that do this in a whiff... take jquery.cycle for example, it even has a light version with only the basics (more than enough for what you need)

Comment: Dude! Can you read? And why you edit my question? You delete most important part of this. I said: i need solution with loading images from server only when need (on event). I dont want to load all this files (even dont know how many pictures i have) on load of page.

Comment: Eh are you talking to me? I did not edit any question, and with those gallery plugins you still don't have to load them all at once... some allow lazy loading...

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an image tag each time you need a new image, and append it to the document and it will be loaded in asynchronously. e.g.:

```
var $img = $("<img/>");
$img[0].src = "foo.jpg";
$("#someDiv").append($img);
```

so you can do something like:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#theImage").attr("src", "parse the number out of the filename, increment, put back");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var info = {
  images : ["/img/1.jpg","/img/2.jpg","/img/3.jpg"],
  current : 0
}
$("#imgID").live("click", function(){
  if(info.current++ > info.images.length) {
    info.current = 0;
  }
  $(this).attr("src",info.images[info.current]);
});


<img id="imgID" src="/img/1.jpg" />
```

I know there are no buttons, but click the images and this should scroll through them.

Comment: `.live` should probably be `.bind`

Comment: You can elminate the `if` statement with `info.current = ++info.current % info.images.length;` so they just loop around. And ditch `$(this)`, use `this.src = info.images[info.current];`

Comment: good stuff Rob. `$(this)`.. clearly I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: well, but this way mean what i know, how many images i have. I wrote before (was edited by rlemon) what i didnt know that and can`t create array in js.